# OpenMP parallel for -- Multiple parallel for's Vs. one parallel that includes within it multiple for's

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp, barrier

I am going through [Using OpenMP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/using-openmp). The authors compare and contrast the following two constructs:

```
//Construct 1
#pragma omp parallel for
for( ... )
{
    /* Work sharing loop 1 */
}
...
#pragma omp parallel for
for( ... )
{
    /* Work sharing loop N */
}
```

as against

```
//Construct 2
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for    
    for( ... )
    {
        /* Work sharing loop 1 */
    }
    ...
    #pragma omp for    
    for( ... )
    {
        /* Work sharing loop N */
    }
}
```

They state that Construct 2

> has fewer implied barriers, and there might be potential for cache
> data reuse between loops. The downside of this approach is that one
> can no longer adjust the number of threads on a per loop basis, but
> that is often not a real limitation.

I am having a difficult time understanding how Construct 2 has fewer implied barriers. Is there not an implied barrier in Construct 2 after each for loop due to `#pragma omp for`? So, in each case, isn't the number of implied barriers the same, `N`? That is, is it not the case in Construct 2 that the first loop occurs first, and so on, and then the `N`th for loop is executed last?

Also, how is Construct 2 more favorable for cache reuse between loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am having a difficult time understanding how Construct 2 has fewer
> implied barriers. Is there not an implied barrier in Construct 2 after
> each for loop due to #pragma omp for? So, in each case, isn't the
> number of implied barriers the same, N? That is, is it not the case in
> Construct 2 that the first loop occurs first, and so on, and then the
> Nth for loop is executed last?

I did not read the book but based on what you have shown it is actually the other way around, namely:

```
 //Construct 1
#pragma omp parallel for
for( ... )
{
    /* Work sharing loop 1 */
} // <-- implicit barrier 
...
#pragma omp parallel for
for( ... )
{
    /* Work sharing loop N */
} // <-- implicit barrier.
```

has **N implicit barriers** (at the end of each *parallel region*), whereas the second code:

```
 //Construct 2
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for    
    for( ... )
    {
        /* Work sharing loop 1 */
    } <-- implicit barrier
    ...
    #pragma omp for    
    for( ... )
    {
        /* Work sharing loop N */
    } <-- implicit barrier
} <-- implicit barrier
```

**has N+1 barriers** (at the end of each *for* + the parallel region).

Actually, in this case, since there is no computation between the last two implicit barriers, one can add the `nowait` to the last `#pragma omp for` to eliminate one of the redundant barriers.

One way for the second code to have fewer implicit barriers than the second would be if you would add a `nowait` clause to the `#pragma omp for` clauses.

From the link about the book that you have shown:

> Finally, Using OpenMP considers trends likely to influence OpenMP
> development, offering a glimpse of the possibilities of a future
> OpenMP 3.0 **from the vantage point of the current OpenMP 2.5.** With
> multicore computer use increasing, the need for a comprehensive
> introduction and overview of the standard interface is clear.

So the book is using the **old** OpenMP 2.5 standard, and from that [standard](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/spec25.pdf) about the *loop* constructor one can read:

> **There is an implicit barrier** at the end of a loop constructor
> **unless a nowait clause is specified.**

A `nowait` cannot be added to the `parallel` constructor but it can be added to the `for` constructor. Therefore, the second code has the **potential** to have fewer implicit barriers if one can add the `nowait` clause to the `#pragma omp for` clauses. However, as it is, the second code has actually more implicit barriers than the first code.

> Also, how is Construct 2 more favorable for cache reuse between loops?

If you are using a `static` distribution of the loop iterations among threads (*e.g.,* `#pragma omp for scheduler(static, ...)` in the second code, the same threads will be working with the same loop iterations. For instance, with two threads let us call them `Thread A` and `Thread B`. If we assume a *static* distribution with `chunk=1`, `Thread A` and `B` will work with the odd and even iterations of each loop, respectively. Consequently, depending on the actual application code, this might mean that those threads will work with the same memory positions of a given data structure (*e.g.,* the same array positions).

In the first code, in theory (however this will depend on the specific OpenMP implementation), since there are two different parallel regions, different threads can pick up *the same* loop iterations across the two loops. In other words, in our example with the two threads, there are no guarantees that the same thread that computed the even (or the odd) numbers in one loop would compute those same numbers in the other loops.